# Run a function for a specified amount of time and stop

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I want to run for a certain number of seconds and then stop. `setTimeout()` doesn't help because it is used to schedule code execution after a designated amount of milliseconds which is quite different for my use case which is to run a function for a designated amount of milliseconds then stop.

Comment: Inside your function I assume it has some looping logic?  If so just break the loop, just use the Date time functions and compare to start time..

Comment: @Keith That will completely freeze your screen.

Comment: @Ivar  it depends...